# My Slideshow Does Not Centre, No Matter What I Try

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css, slideshow

I have an automatically playing slideshow (controlled by jQuery/JS), that requires each image to be absolutely positioned. The problem is that I'm trying to horizontally centre this slideshow on my page, but nothing I try seems to work. The slideshow must not only be centred at full-screen width, but also when the browser is resized.

From what I understand, anything that is positioned absolutely should be positioned relative to the next positioned ancestor. In my code, this ancestor  happens to be the ".fadein" div (I think? Or should it be the "#slideshow" div?), which is positioned relatively. Therefore, if I position this ".fadein" div, the slideshow should, in theory, also move around the page.

And this does work. I can relatively position the ".fadein" div by 100px (or whatever) from the left (or any side), and the slideshow also moves.

But I can't find any reliable method that positions the slideshow in the horizontal centre of my page without either:

1) causing additional "white space" to one side of the image, which results in a scroll bar along the bottom of the page leading to nothing.

2) preventing the image from resizing when the browser is resized.

**Edit 1:** I was able to get the slideshow centred, but can't find a way to have it resize yet...

Hopefully someone can help me with this problem. Thanks!

```js
   $(function() {

    $('.fadein img:gt(0)').hide();
    
    setInterval(function() {
    
     $('.fadein :first-child').fadeOut(2000)
      
         .next('img').fadeIn(2000)
         
         .end().appendTo('.fadein');
         
     }, 5000);
});
```

```css
.fadein {
 position:relative;
}

.fadein img{
 position:absolute;
 left:0;
}
```

```html
<div id="slideshow">

  <div class="fadein">
    
   <img src="http://placehold.it/350x150" />
    <img src="http://placehold.it/350x150" />
   <img src="http://placehold.it/350x150" />
   <img src="http://placehold.it/350x150" />
   <img src="http://placehold.it/350x150" />
   <img src="http://placehold.it/350x150" />
   
  </div>
   
</div>
```

**Edit 2:** I found the centring worked well in Safari (Mac), but did not work well in Firefox (Mac). Why might this be? The following is what I have now (edited a little to fit with the flow of my page, but I have done nothing that would alter the layout in FF. In FF, the slideshow os now about 600px to the right, so it is off the screen. In Safari, it fits very nicely, without any scrolling necessary.

```css
.fadein {
 position:relative;
 top:70px;
 height:100%;
}

.fadein img {
 position:absolute;
 left:50%;
 top:50%;
 -webkit-transform: translate(-50%, -0%);
}

#slideshow {
 max-width:100%;
 height:100%;
}
```

```html
<div id="slideshow">

  <div class="fadein">
    
   <img src="http://placehold.it/350x150" />
    <img src="http://placehold.it/350x150" />
   <img src="http://placehold.it/350x150" />
   <img src="http://placehold.it/350x150" />
   <img src="http://placehold.it/350x150" />
   <img src="http://placehold.it/350x150" />
   
  </div>
   
</div>
```

Comment: I would suggest using placehold.it for placeholder images for use on stack overflow, you basically can have urls that will allow everyone to see such as set your image source to http://placehold.it/350x150

Comment: Right, thanks for the tip @Charles380.

Answer (score 0):

You could actually use calc from css for example:

```
.your-absolute-element {
  position: absolute;
  left: calc(50% - sizeOfElement);
}
```

It is an option, there are many ways to make a center align for centering boxes.

Answer (score 0):

```js
$(function() {

    $('.fadein img:gt(0)').hide();
    
    setInterval(function() {
    
     $('.fadein :first-child').fadeOut(2000)
      
         .next('img').fadeIn(2000)
         
         .end().appendTo('.fadein');
         
     }, 5000);
});
```

```css
body,html {
position:relative;
  height: 100%;
}

.fadein {
 position:relative;
  height: 100%;
}

.fadein img{
 position:absolute;
 left:50%;
  top: 50%;
  -webkit-transform: translate(-50%, -50%);
}

#slideshow {
position:absolute;
  width: 100%;
  height: 100%;
}
```

```html
<div id="slideshow">

  <div class="fadein">
    
   <img src="http://placehold.it/350x150" />
    <img src="http://placehold.it/350x150" />
   <img src="http://placehold.it/350x150" />
   <img src="http://placehold.it/350x150" />
   <img src="http://placehold.it/350x150" />
   <img src="http://placehold.it/350x150" />
   
  </div>
   
</div>
```

Comment: I tried this, and it centres the image/s perfectly, but will not resize it/them. I'm thinking this should now be a simple fix, but I'm still trying to get my head around it...